# Wygwam - stripping tags from ul li (class and id) [Advanced Content Filter (ACF)]

Tags: wygwam

Good afternoon,

after upgrading to the latest wygwam version i experienced the problem that the editor is stripping out content from wygwam fields. Not the visible parts but class and id fields from for example ul and li fields.

Most likely the new Advanced Content Filter (ACF) ckeditor implemented is the root cause of this because they have switched it to default on. Problem is that there doesn't seem to that pixel and tonic didn't update the ADVANCED SETTINGS tab so you can disable ACF, only add extraAllowedContent.

My question is, how do i disable ACF? I must set CKEDITOR.config.allowedContent to true to do this but WHERE?

http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_advanced_content_filter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can disable CKEditor’s content filtering functionality by going to Add-Ons > Modules > Wygwam > [your config name], and changing the “Restrict allowed HTML?” setting to “No”.

That’s a new setting as of Wygwam 3.1, so you may have to update Wygwam first.