# Issues with deleted code

Tags: ee2, tags

I am having issues with the text editor in EE deleting code that I add to pages. We are wanting to style our support pages a certain way, and I need to be able to add divs and classes to existing p, ul, li, and other tags.

For example:

I have this content on a page:

[p]Getting Started[/p]

[ul]
    [li]FAQ[/li]
    [li]Support Contacts[/li]
[/ul]

if I wrap it in a div, like this:

[div class="support-content"]

[p]Getting Started[/p]

[ul]
    [li]FAQ[/li]
    [li]Support Contacts[/li]
[/ul]
[/div]

and save, it keeps the div I added, but when I go to edit the page again, it deletes the div.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening, or turn off the rich text editor for certain pages so I can just directly edit the source code?

Thanks!

Comment: Which rich text editor are you using - tinyMCE, or a Wygwam field (CKEditor)?

Comment: We're using Wygwam (3.1.2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure Wygwam/CKeditor to ignore certain tags and classes/not strip them out.

I found something that may be similar over on Stackoverflow: [CKEditor strips classes from divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15659390/ckeditor-automatically-strips-classes-from-div). In your case, you're seeing Wygwam/CKEditor strip the whole div. Apparently, though, you can configure your instance of Wygwam fields to ignore certain types of code, and/or leave classes alone.

So I did a little more searching and found this on this subsite: [Wygwam - stripping tags from ul li (class and id) [Advanced Content Filter (ACF)]](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/13095/wygwam-stripping-tags-from-ul-li-class-and-id-advanced-content-filter-acf) that deals directly with configuring ckeditor in Wygwam. I think these two questions, and their answers, will be helpful to you.

Comment: Thanks, Leigh!  I'll give this a shot and see how it works.  Will reply here with the outcome either way.